# How to send OSC to QLab with Java?

Tags: java, slf4j, osc, javaosc

I am trying to send OSC (Open Sound Control) to Figure 53's QLab.  So far I have come up with this code.

```
import com.illposed.osc.transport.udp.OSCPortOut;

import com.illposed.osc.OSCMessage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        OSCPortOut sender = new OSCPortOut(InetAddress.getByName("10.67.192.113"), 53000);
        OSCMessage msg = new OSCMessage("/cue/1");
         try {
            sender.send(msg);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

I have successfully added Illposed's JavaOSC library to my code, but then it says I need SLF4J, and when I try to add `slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar` it says `Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".` When I try to run the above code with both libraries SLF4J and JavaOSC.

Comment: are you using maven? in that case you have to add the dependency to pom.xml instead of adding the jar...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Maven to handle the dependencies JavaOSC needs.

Here's a good tutorial for Eclipse. Just use a simple project, you do not need to do archetype selection.

Then add the following at the end of your new projects pom.xml file, before
`</project>`
but after everything else.

```
`<dependency>`
    <groupId>com.illposed.osc</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaosc-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```